# city and country name auto populate in search area

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

hello I am working on swift. In my app I need user to select his country and city. As I am newbie so I don't know how other apps implement this kind a functionality. what I have tried so far is

I have implemented three tableviews countryTableView, stateTableView and cityTableView. But I find this process is very long because user has to navigate three times. Btw I was populating the data from the mysql database saved at my web server

I need to implement this feature like this [image]

so when user types city or city in the searchBar, app would show the city and country name in the suggestion. Is there any library available online ? I have tried to check the google api but I think it gives many other entries too like places etc But not sure. Do I have to implement this from scratch? and if I have to implement it from scratch, do I have to save this countries,cities, states in backend server or in app core data ? Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

iOS has a option called `UISearchResultsController`. As already you have data in back-end to populate by filtering based on the user input. `UISearchBar` is the one which embedded with `UISearchResultsController`. Use a delegate method of the `UISearchBar` i.e `- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString`. From this method make a call your backend database, once data received `UISearchResultsController` also has a `UITableview` embedded, you can handle this tableview population as same as how you can do with normal `UITableView`.